# Generate a list of rentals, with the client's information for the outlet with the most rentals

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables : RentalAgreement (Rentals), Clients, vehicle and outlet. 
I need to list rentalAgreementNumbers of THE outlet with the highest rentals with client info and outlet address.

Thanks!

So far, I am getting all 11 rows - that is, all agreements for all outlets

```
SELECT outlet.Street || ' ' || outlet.City || ', ' || outlet.state || ' - ' || outlet.zipcode AS "Outlet Street Address", rentalNo AS "ID", startDate AS "Start Date", returnDate AS "Return Date", clientName, client.Phone
FROM
client JOIN (ragreement JOIN (vehicle JOIN outlet USING (outNo)) USING (licenseNo)) USING (clientNo)
GROUP BY outlet.Street || ' ' || outlet.City || ', ' || outlet.state || ' - ' || outlet.zipcode, rentalNo, startDate, returnDate, clientName, client.Phone
    HAVING COUNT(rentalNo) = (SELECT
    MAX(COUNT(rentalNo))
    FROM
    ragreement
    GROUP BY (rentalNo));
```

How can I modify this to get only 5 rental agreements listed for outlet1 - which has the highest rental agreements in my table?

Answer (score 0):

After the select command, you can set a limit. Mssql syntaxt for this is

```sql
Select top(5) [columns] from....
```

You also need to add a order by clause at the end of the query

```sql
... Order by [columns or calculations]
```

Comment: This will not work, I need a generalized  query, not a modified one. Top 5 will work only for my table, this query needs to be universal.